# How to Change a page template dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, templates

I want to change the inner template of my page on some click event, but without changing the master layout.

The page contents are stored in Database.And each template is given an ID.

The issue is how to display the new template?
Is this possible? Any ideas or suggestions are welcome...

Iam using MVC3.
Can i use partial views as templates and load this view on ajax call ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial view with ajax calls is the best solution for MVC3 razor template!
(eg : $('#container').load('_yourPartial.cshtml', '#right');)

Sample : http://www.codemein.net/2012/05/how-to-refresh-partial-view-with-ajax-asp-net/ (not from me)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create http handler.
Use jQuery to call it.
And use jTemplate for your formating.

Here are few links

http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/01/05/using-the-jtemplate-jquery-plugin-with-ajax-and-asp-net/

http://encosia.com/use-asp-nets-httphandler-to-bridge-the-cross-domain-gap/
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=573

Answer (score 0):

without any more information about what's a template for you i can only tell you that you can use UpdatePanel or Ajax.Load function in order to dynamcly load a new part of the page. (Or change the whole page without reload it).

Comment: as i was using MVC3 i used partialview for this and used the ajax.beginform. Please advice if this is not a better way. Thanks for the response.